# How to check value of finalizer?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `PV` which looks as below:

```
[root@master nfs-static]# kubectl describe pv
Name:            pv007
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     <none>
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:
Status:          Available
Claim:
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWX
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        3Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:      NFS (an NFS mount that lasts the lifetime of a pod)
    Server:    fs-053473b593093bdb9.efs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
    Path:      /
    ReadOnly:  false
Events:        <none>
[root@master nfs-static]#
```

Now, I am able to `patch` the finalizer value using the command:

```
kubectl patch pv pv007 -p '{"metadata": {"finalizers": null}}'
```

**Which kubectl command to use to see the value given to finalizer??**

I am executing `kubectl describe pv pv007` but it is not showing value of finalizer.

Comment: I have updated my question and added kubectl details.

Comment: kubectl get pv <pvname> -o yaml

Answer (score 1):

If the PV is struck in terminating status after deleting the corresponding pods, please use the below command to clear the PV successfully.

```
kubectl patch pv pv007 -p '{"metadata": {"finalizers": null}}'
```

This command will set the `finalizers` setting to null and this allows the final unmount from the node, and it can be deleted accordingly.
When you delete an object which has a finalizer, `deletionTimestamp` is added to `resource metadata` making the object read-only. Only exception to the read-only rule, is that finalizers can be removed. Once all finalizers are gone, the object is queued to be deleted.

```
kubectl get pv pv007
```

The above command will provide the details of pv **pv007** if it is still in terminating status.

```
kubectl get pv
```

The above command will provide the list of all PVs which are in **terminating** or **bound** status.

For more information, please refer to the [documentation](https://veducate.co.uk/kubernetes-pvc-terminating/) written by **Dean Lewis.**